# TeamCity property to get clone directory?

Tags: mercurial, teamcity-7.1

We use TeamCity with mercurial and leave the "Clone Repository To" field empty so the path is auto-generated.

I have a configuration template where I would like to add a build step that needs to access the `.hg` directory.

I know that TeamCity clones repositories to `data\system\caches\mercurial\hg_somenumbers` so is there any way to get this path?